# increment Row Index every 5 rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to write function to get values from `CutomersSupport` Sheet and increment row index every 5 rows

[image: Wrong Function]

What Function Could i use here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in a cell and fill down.

```
=INDEX(CustomersSupport!A:X, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/5)+6, MOD((ROW(1:1)-1)*3, 15)+12)
```

The functions and maths can be tested by putting the following into the top of an unused column and filling down.

```
=ADDRESS(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/5)+6, MOD((ROW(1:1)-1)*3, 15)+12, 4, 1, "CustomersSupport")
```

[image]

Comment: it' not from A to X. it's L, O, R, U, X

Comment: Yes, I could have made a small maths adjustment (change +12 to +1) and used L:X but this may be more transparent as the column maths start at 12 (i.e column L). In any event, the results are correct.

Comment: the address formula works perfectly, but the first one isn't :(

Comment: it's very useful i changed +6 to +5 `=INDEX(CustomersSupport!A:X, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/5)+5, MOD((ROW(1:1)-1)*3, 15)+12)` and it works now. thank you

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to paint the formulas directly into the worksheet with a short macro:

```
Sub formulaPainter()
    Dim rng As Range, arr, nStart As Long, nEnd As Long, i As Long
    Dim s As String, j As Long
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set rng = Range("B9")
    s = "=CustomersSupport!"
    nStart = 6
    nEnd = 120
    arr = Array("L", "O", "R", "U", "X")
    j = 1

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    For i = nStart To nEnd
        For Each a In arr
            rng.Offset(j - 1, 0).Formula = s & a & i
            j = j + 1
        Next a
    Next i
End Sub
```

In this case:

1. *rng* is the start location for the set of formulas
2. *nStart* is the starting number
3. *nEnd* is the ending number
4. *arr* defines the set of columns

[image]